# Different KeySizes from Different Stores same pfx

Tags: certificates

Sorry, i'm new to all of this.

I have a question as to why the KeySize of a RSACryptoServiceProvider will differ between Store Locations?

I've imported the same pfx in the LocalMachine store, as well as the CurrentUser sotre. When I ran a verify against a signed string, against the public key, the CurrentUser pfx verifies the data, but, the LocalMachine failed to.

If I do print out the KeySizes of the two stores, the CurrentUser store size is 2048, and the LocalMachine is 1024.

Any idea?

This is on Windows7 x64

Thx

Comment: Can you reproduce this with dummy PFXs (I suppose you don't want to reveal the real PFXs) and then post lots more detail here?

Comment: Ok, no problem. Will see what I can do...